# Draw a triangle offset by number of days from the last bar

Tags: plot

I'm trying to add a triangle offset by number of days that the Moving Average is calculated with to have a quick view on what data is included in its calculation. But I cannot find a way to draw one triangle offset by number of days from the last day. I have no idea why any way I try, I get triangles all over the place.
Help greatly appreciated.

```
// Define the offset
offset = 5

// Calculate the position of the triangle
triangle_x = bar_index[offset]
triangle_y = low[offset]

// Plot the triangle
plotshape(series=triangle_y, location=location.belowbar, color=color.blue, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.small, x=triangle_x, y=triangle_y)
```

Thanks